# Is the Special case pattern redundant in Swift?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, coding-style

In Robert Martin's Clean Code book there is a Java example of when to use the [special case pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html). Rather than write this:

```
try {
  MealExpenses expenses = expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.getID());
  expenseTotal += expenses.getTotal();
} catch(MealExpensesNotFound e) {
  expenseTotal += getMealPerDiem();
}
```

We'd use:

```
public class PerDiemMealExpenses implements MealExpenses {
  public int getTotal() {
  // return the per diem default
}
```

and

```
MealExpenses expenses = expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.getID());
expenseTotal += expenses.getTotal();
```

In swift we have nil coalescing so we can skip creating an interface/protocol and go immediately to:

```
let expenses = expenseReportCalculator.getMeals(employee.id)
expenseTotal += expenses.getTotal() ?? getMealPerDiem
```

Does this mean the special case pattern is redundant when using Swift? Perhaps I'm either missing the point or there are special circumstances in which this pattern would be valuable.

Comment: Is that `getMealPerDiem` a constant somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's a function, I forgot to put type the brackets in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this "special case" discussion, in the *Define Normal Flow* section of the *Error Handling* chapter of Martin's excellent *[Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882),* is a bit unswifty.

As you point out, part of Martin's rationale is to excise the repeated use of Java's "awkward" (his words, not mine) `try`-`catch` pattern, especially if you're repeating it a lot. But in Swift, if there are no expenses, you would probably not pursue an error throwing pattern, but rather just return an optional. And, as you say, the Swift `nil`-coalescing pattern is comparably elegant to the `try`-`catch` pattern. (As an aside, Swift optionals renders irrelevant the next two sections in that chapter, too, *Don't Return Null* and *Don't Pass Null*.)

Robert Martin credits Martin Fowler in this discussion, but in *[Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672),* Fowler discusses "special case" pattern in the context the challenges of `null` checks in Java and all the problems that entails. But Swift handles optionals so much more gracefully and it renders much of Fowler's defensive-`null` discussions moot.

So, I agree, that `MealExpenses` is not a particularly good candidate for the "special case" pattern in Swift. (Frankly, I'm not sure it's a great candidate in general, regardless.) Optionals would be a more natural Swift solution. Now, if I were littering my code with the identical `nil` coalescing pattern all over the place, I'd look for ways to avoid repeating it, but I wouldn't necessarily jump to introduce the "special case" pattern solely for this purpose.

It's worth noting that in *[Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672),* Fowler offers an expanded "special case" example, where a landlord's "customer" for some random building might be "no customer" (e.g. the building is vacant), an "unknown customer" (you know that there is a tenant, but you don't know who it is), or a particular customer. This ternary state is one where we have to start to think beyond a simple Swift optional. But at that point we might use an `enum` with associated values, or you could conceivably use the "special case" pattern (but now needing to introduce a protocol). It depends upon particular situation. With all of that said, I've yet to encounter scenarios where I've felt inclined to add "special case" pattern in my Swift code.